# Modify AMI attribute [create volume] via AWS API or CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have shared a bunch of AMIs from an AWS account to another.

I used this `EC2conn1.modify_image_attribute(AMI_id, operation='add', attribute='launchPermission', user_ids=[second_aws_account_id])` to do it.

But, by only adding launch permission for the 2nd account, I can launch an instance but I cannot copy the shared AMI to another region [in the 2nd account].

When I tick the checkbox to "create volume" from the UI of the 1st account, I can copy the shared AMI from the 2nd:

[image: 1st account AMI permissions]

I can modify the launch permissions using the `modify_image_attribute` function from [boto](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/ec2.html).

In the documentation says, `attribute (string) – The attribute you wish to change` but I understand that it can only change the launch permissions and add an account.

Yet, the `get_image_attribute` has 3 options `Valid choices are: * launchPermission * productCodes * blockDeviceMapping`.

So, is there a way to programmatically change it from the API along with the launch permissions or, it has not been implemented yet??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console uses the API so there's almost nothing you can do in the console that you can't to using the API.

Remember that an AMI is just a configuration entity -- basic launch configuration, linked to (not containing) one or more backing snapshots, which are technically separate entities.

The console is almost certainly making an additional API request the [ModifySnapshotAttribute](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_ModifySnapshotAttribute.html) API when it offers to optionally "add Create Volume permissions to the following associated snapshot."

See also http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-modifying-snapshot-permissions.html

Presumably, copying a snapshot to another region relies on the same "Create Volume" permission (indeed, you'll see that a copied snapshot has a fake source volume ID, presumably an artifact of the copying process).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know these details and it helped me search to the right direction. Indeed I was missing a step that I needed to make with a separate API call. I will post my code for reference..

Answer (score 1):

Based on the accepted answer, this is the code I wrote for anyone interested.

```
# Add copy permission to the image's snapshot
# Find the snapshot of the specific AMI
image_object = EC2conn.get_image(AMI_id)

# Grab the block device mapping dynamically
ami_devices = []
for key in image_object.block_device_mapping.iterkeys():
    # print key #debug
    ami_devices.append(key)
# print ami_devices #debug

for ami_device in ami_devices:
    snap_id = image_object.block_device_mapping[ami_device].snapshot_id

    # Add permission
    EC2conn.modify_snapshot_attribute(snap_id, attribute='createVolumePermission', operation='add', user_ids=second_aws_account_id)
    print "{0} [{1}] Permission added to snapshot".format(AMI_name,snap_id)
```